How to detect even or odd minutes in bash script
I need to detect whether the current minutes are even or odd regardless of the time zone. I tried this according to answers from several sites:
#!/bin/bash 
n=$(date +"%M")
r=`expr$n%2`
if [ r -eq 0 ] 
then 
echo "Even minute"
else 
echo "Odd minute"
 fi

When I run the script I get
./Odd_even.sh: line 5: expr04%2: command not found
./Odd_even.sh: line 6: [: r: integer expression expected – 

What is wrong here?

What is the question?

What is wrong here, because when I run the script I get :

./Odd_even.sh: line 5: expr04%2: command not found
./Odd_even.sh: line 6: [: r: integer expression expected

expr is an external command like ls and like any command you are required to use spaces to separate the command from its arguments.

Working with hours or minutes as numbers in bash has a nasty edge case: bash treats numbers with a leading zero as octal, and 08 and 09 are invalid octal numbers:
min=09
echo $(( min % 2 == 0 ))

bash: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")

Use %-M as the format directive -- it will return the minutes with no leading zero.

Additionally:

bash can do arithmetic, you don't need to call out to expr
if (( n % 2 == 0 )); then
  echo "$n is even"
else
  echo "$n is odd"
fi


and bash can do strftime-like things. The %()T directive in bash's builtin printf allows the date format string inside the parentheses. In this simple case, you don't need to call out to date.
minute=$(printf '%(%-M)T' -1)   # -1 is a special value that means "now"
# or even
printf -v minute '%(%-M)T' -1




Thanks glenn, works great. Final version: :#!/bin/bash
n=$(date +"%-M")
if (( n % 2 == 0 )); then
echo "$n is even"
else
echo "$n is odd"
fi

What should I do when someone answers my question?
